# How to get python to recognize string value in DBF as part of if/else statements?

Tags: python, dbf

I am building a program to write new values to a dbf based on different conditions but I am having an issue with python not recognizing text values as a part of if/else statements.

if I have "col1" filled with true/false values and I want to say:

```
my_table.add_fields('col2 N(2,0)')

for record in dbf.Process(my_table):
    if record.col1 == 'true':
        record.col2 = 1
    else: 
        record.col2 = 2
```

How do I get python to recognize 'true/false' as a value as a part of that statement?

Comment: What happens if you just use `if record.col1:` or `if bool(record.col1):`?

Comment: bool() probably won't work as I want to deal with text values other than true/false, just used true/false in my example for simplicity.  

I don't understand what you mean by just saying
    
    if record.col1:

for the first line??

Comment: So `col1` is not just `'true'` and `'false'`? What error are you getting with the code you have posted?

Comment: I don't recieve any error message.  What happens is python will recognize the line 4 as false (regardless of true/false as value) and input '2' in col2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What data type is `col1`?  Basic dbf data types are `Char` (text), `Date` (datetime), `Logical` (boolean) `Number` (integer/float), `Float` (integer/float), and `Memo` (unbounded text).

If `col1` is not a Char field, comparing to a string will always return False.  If `col1` is a Char field, then it will compare equal only when `col1` is excatly 'true' -- not 'true ' or 'True' or 'TRUE'.

If the problem is extra spaces (by default my module returns the entire field, including trailing spaces) you can either do:

```
if record.col1.strip() == 'true':
```

or tell `dbf.Table` to use a custom `Char` type that ignores trailing spaces:

```
my_table = dbf.Table('/path/to/file', default_data_types={'C':dbf.Char})
```

Comment: odd, those both seem to do the trick, even though my values appear to have no spaces at all..  Thank you very much Ethan, would up vote 5x if I could!

Comment: @user21267: So vote once, and accept the answer (click on the green check mark by my question. ;)  The reason this problem shows up is that if the field size is 7, what gets returned is `true _ _ _` (where the underscores represent spaces).

Comment: Apparently not enough rep to upvote :(  and that makes complete sense.  Thank you Ethan